# automatically creating a folder in sftp

Tags: mule, mule-studio

How can i create a folder/directory in the sftp server using mule sftp connector, if it is'nt existing.
another issue that I have is I need these file names suffixed with the dates.

eg:
the folder structure created should be like 
QA_23NOV2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with the connector.
You need to implement that somehow with custom code.

https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-5192